# Mask RCNN Memory management

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, gpu

I am trying to fit the model into memory.
I saw that one of the possible solutions is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
```

or this aporoach:

```
#config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.4 #Allocate fixed memory
```

And finally

```
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

I wonder where do I supposed to put this?